# How to manipulate a component's children using ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

How do I manipulate the DOM the React way?

Let's say I have some component and I use it to check if the children of type input is empty: how can I do that?

Keep in mind that the component's children are variable, that's why I can't manually assign a reference to each of them.

```
function MyComponent({ children }) {
  return <div className="my-component">{children}</div>;
}

...

return (
  <MyComponent>
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="phone" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </MyComponent>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to clone and inject a handler on each, keeping around info about if it the input has text, or if the new value is empty, this is just a really rough example of what that might look like:

```
function MyComponent({ children }) {
  let seen = {};
  function generalHandler(ev) { 
      console.log(ev.target.getAttribute('key'))
      let key = ev.target.getAttribute('key');
      seen[key] = true;
      ev.target.value ? del seen[key] : false;
  };
  this.state = { updatedChildren: React.Children.map(children, (child, key) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {"key": key,
                                        "className": "my-component", 
                                        "onKeyUp": generalHandler})
      })
  }
  function updateTheChildState() { 
       // do some state changes
       this.setState({updatedChildren}); 
  }
  render() {
      return (
              <div className="my-component">this.state.updatedChildren</div>;
             )
  }
}
```

Comment: Don´t simply iterate over `children`. Use `React.Children` top-level api to work with the `children` prop (e.g. `React.Children.map`). [Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren).

Comment: @Rallen Thanks for catching that.